# Executable related issue

Tags: powerbuilder

We have an application which has been developed in PowerBuilder 9.

The problem is we have implemented a window for changing the password. In the window we have a field for the old password. When we change that password via EXE, it doesn't allow us to enter a password with more than 8 characters. But our existing password has 9 characters.

The following properties are checked:

1. Old password field size. (There is no limit)
2. Executed the application via PB 9 IDE (No issues, also I can do enter more that 8 characters).
3. The problem only happens with the compiled EXE.
4. Checked the desktop theme (No luck)

Is there any solution for this issue?

Comment: When building the executable, do you choose to compile to p-code or machine code?

Comment: I checked the project object there we haven't selected the machine code check box. What is P-code?

Comment: I have some more question. 
1. When we executes applcation from PB IDE, where the font size will get from? Because our Password changed window has bigger size in Old password field, But when we executes the same window from PB IDE it doesn't take that bigger size. What is the reason it does not take set size from property? Why it applies the set size for EXE?

Comment: pcode is bytecode for the PowerBuilder virtual machine (the pbvm100.dll), while the machine code is actual x86 code. machine code is produced by translating pcode to C/C++ then compiling it. It used to be faster, but nowadays it is also more buggy and pcode is not that slower than machine code.

Comment: What is the "field" UI: DataWindow column field or SingleLineEdit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why the text size may differ between the two versions, but if it is different perhaps you cannot enter all the text with the bigger font due to a disabled `AutoHScroll` property of the text field?

I realize that the different display may come from the `Windows classic style` option from the  `General` tab of the compilation properties.

Comment: So it was the disabled `AutoHScroll`?

Comment: yes, I went and enabled that. Thanks Seki. I looked only reducing font size just like login window.